# How is a pathspec supposed to work?

Tags: git, git-status

I am observing a strange behavior while using git-status with pathspecs. I would like your opinion on whether it is the expected behavior, or an undefined behavior in git.

**Initial setup**

```
$ mkdir main && cd main
$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in d:/temp/main/.git/
$ touch test[1].txt
$ touch test[2].txt
```

**The following ones are understandable**

```
$ # 1. escaped square brackets
$ git status test\[1\].txt --short        
?? test[1].txt

$ # 2. escaped square brackets with range
$ git status test\[[1-9]\].txt --short    
?? test[1].txt
?? test[2].txt

$ # 3. unmatched range, with what looks like a fallback to literal comparison
$ git status test[1].txt --short          
?? test[1].txt
```

**Additional setup for unexpected behavior**

```
$ touch test1.txt
```

**Unexpected behavior**

```
$ # 4. matched range, so no fallback to literal comparison (this one looks OK)
$ git status test[1].txt --short
?? test1.txt

$ # 5. escaped square brackets => I would expect only test[1].txt to be returned
$ git status test\[1\].txt --short
?? test1.txt
?? test[1].txt

$ # 6. escaped square brackets with range => I would expect only test[1].txt 
$ # and test[2].txt to be returned
$ git status test\[[1-9]\].txt --short
?? test1.txt
?? test[1].txt
?? test[2].txt

$ # 7. only escaping the last square bracket
$ # result looks similar to the 5th case
$ git status test[1\].txt --short
?? test1.txt
?? test[1].txt
```

**Additional setup for more fun**

```
$ git add test1.txt
$ rm test1.txt
$ touch test2.txt
```

**More unexpected behavior**

```
$ # 8. ???
$ git status test[1].txt --short
AD test1.txt
?? test[1].txt

$ # 9. We lost test1.txt ???
$ git status test[1-2].txt --short
?? test2.txt

$ # Woo... Should this really work?
$ git status test[*.txt --short
AD test1.txt
?? test2.txt
?? test[1].txt
?? test[2].txt
```

I'm a bit confused there. I've read the Git documentation related to [pathspec](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary.html) and it's not that detailed.

Could anyone help me understand the logic behind?

Comment: We actually need to know the shell you are using

Comment: @AntoinePelisse It was GitBash on msysgit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of things to discuss here but I will try to focus on: **1.** the logic behind this, **2.** How it modifies the behavior.

## The logic

Most of the *path expansion* is done by the shell (hence my comment). Some is done by git, when it has what it takes.

## Some tests

### The setup

I used this program to investigate the issue:

```
include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            puts(argv[i]);
    }
}
```

I know, it's very high-skill programming.

### Tests

We can now have a look at what is going on, and see how the shell modifies what git receives:

**Point 1, 2, 3, 4**: Everything is working fine, running the small program will give you the same.

```
$ ./a.out test\[1\].txt test\[[1-9]\].txt test[1].txt
test[1].txt
test[1].txt
test[2].txt
test[1].txt
```

**Point 5, 6, 7**: This time it's handled by Git, behavior is not that surprising (doing both glob and literal comparison)

```
$ ./a.out test\[1\].txt test\[[1-9]\].txt test[1\].txt
test[1].txt
test[1].txt
test[2].txt
test[1].txt
```

**Point 8, 9, 10**: Well, according to what we've seen before, it's no longer surprising. For **9.**, no bash comparison matches with test1.txt (removed, hence, ... removed)

```
$ ./a.out test[1].txt                         
test[1].txt

$ ./a.out test[1-2].txt          
test2.txt

$ ./a.out test[*.txt
test[1].txt
test[2].txt
```

### Conclusion

If you want to test the way Git handles pathspec, you should enclose your path in double quotes:

```
$ ./a.out "test[*.txt" "test[1\].txt"
test[*.txt
test[1\].txt
```

Hope it helped,